# Formatting calculated values in Adobe Document Generation API

Tags: adobe-documentgeneration

In the template language docs for [Adobe Document Generation](https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/docs.html), mathematical expressions can be done using tags like below...

```
{{expr(revenue - expenditure)}}
```

This works and outputs a number, but is there any way to apply formatting to the number, for example, $50,000.00 where the calculated value is just 50000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that doc gen uses JSONata (https://docs.jsonata.org/overview.html) for it's template parsing. As I've learned and played with docgen, the JSONata docs have been *really* helpful. For this particular example, there's a function built in documented under [Numeric functions](https://docs.jsonata.org/numeric-functions) - `$formatNumber`. At minimum it takes a number input and a mask. So to format it as you would want, use:

```
{{$formatNumber(revenue-expenditure, '#,###.00')}}
```

Notice that you don't use `expr` above, just the function.